Progressive metadata pull feature - how to use
Has anyone use Sitecore's "Progressive metadata pull" serialization setting that was added for pulling large content data from XM Cloud?
Ref: https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_CLI/6x/Sitecore_CLI_6023/Release_Notes

Once you have installed the lasted Sitecore cli to latest version 6.0.23
by using
dotnet tool update sitecore.cli
dotnet sitecore plugin init --overwrite

This command will update all the packages to 6.0.23,
Also we need to update the sitecore.json file for the highlighted property "progressiveMetadataPull" to true apart from that there is no further configuration required.

Thats the only change we need to do, then automatically the metadata content from sitecore will be pushed or pulled without timeout issue in a batch process.
We can use the normal way of pulling and pushing content to and from sitecore and local machine using cli command like
dotnet sitecore serialization pull -n dev

Note: I have already checked with the sitecore support on the same before on this.
Now I can pull and push the content without timeout issue.
I hope this helps :)
